# kube-dns pod in ContainerCreating status using Weavenet with no endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns, weave

I am trying to setup a simple cluster won Ubuntu 16.0.4. I followed Kubernetes documentation to create cluster using kubeadm. Below are the versions in have -

## kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.1", GitCommit:"b0b7a323cc5a4a2019b2e9520c21c7830b7f708e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-03T20:44:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T16:24:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

## kubeadm version

kubeadm version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6+", GitVersion:"v1.6.0-alpha.0.2074+a092d8e0f95f52", GitCommit:"a092d8e0f95f5200f7ae2cba45c75ab42da36537", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-13T17:03:18Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Kubelet - 1.5.6 (had to downgrade from 1.6 due to issues with node status NotReady)
Used weave-kube-1.6 add-on.
Docker  Version:      1.12.6

Even after installing pod network using Weavenet, the kube-dns pod is not in running state.

## kubectl get pods -n kube-system

NAME                         READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
etcd-km                      1/1       Running             5          13h
kube-apiserver-km            1/1       Running             2          13h
kube-controller-manager-km   1/1       Running             4          13h
kube-dns-3913472980-xw6mq    0/3       ContainerCreating   0          1h
kube-proxy-p3jhx             1/1       Running             1          1d
kube-proxy-qd1c6             1/1       Running             3          1d
kube-scheduler-km            1/1       Running             7          13h
weave-net-g1fcm              2/2       Running             4          12h
weave-net-t8zsb              2/2       Running             0          12h

## iptables-save

[....]
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp has no endpoints" -m tcp --dport 53 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns has no endpoints" -m udp --dport 53 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

I disabled firewall with ufw stop/ufw disable. I also tried opening up ports 53 on TCP and UDP, but no help. Please help to get my kube-dns pods running.

Thanks much.

Comment: update - the issue got resolved with kubernetes 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved by upgrading to Kubernetes 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and yes it is resolved now. I used flannel for networking and worked well even with Kubernetes 1.6.1 though: https://crondev.com/kubernetes-installation-kubeadm/